# why do we have to add NULL to print a reserve string using pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, null

This is a program in C to print a string in reverse using a pointer.
What is the meanning of `*pre='\0'`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char string[50],reserve[50];
   char *ps = string;
   char *pre = reserve;
   int i=-1;
   printf(" Input a string : ");
   scanf("%s",string);
   while(*ps)
   {
      ps++;
      i++;
   }
   while(i>=0)
   {
      ps--;
      *pre = *ps;
      pre++;
      --i;
   }
   *pre='\0';
   printf(" Reverse of the string is : %s\n\n",reserve);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without a `'\0'` byte at the end, it is not a *string*. That's how strings in C are defined: a sequence of `char` ending with `'\0'`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",s);`?  Where is `s` defined?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  this line: `scanf("%s",s);`  has 3 problems: 1) the array `s` is not defined.  2) always check the returned value, not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 3) when using the input/format specifier: `%s`, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so the input cannot overflow the buffer.  Such buffer overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `char s[20];  if( 1 != scanf( "%19s", s ) ) { handle error }`

Comment: My bad. That's S which i mean string. I edited.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `*pre='\0';` is an idiomatic way of adding a NUL-terminator to the end of your `char[]` array. This is required for the C string type functions to work: e.g. the `printf` call with `%s` specifier.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `%s` in `printf` and it expects its argument to be null terminated. It is not necessary to null terminate if you are treating `reverse` as a character array and then you can use a loop and print the reversed string character by character.

Answer (score 0):

```
*pre='\0';
```

Here backward slash is for escape sequence and 0 is representing  the null character`'\0'`. In C language we use null character to end the string. So suppose you ask user to enter string.

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

Here user enter **stackoverflow** so total 13 characters. But to store that string actually we need an array size of 14. Because we have have to add null character at the end of string.
Here, in our String data will store something like this...

```
s[]={'s','t','a','c','k','o','v','e','r','f','l','o','w','\0'};
```

So Question is why do we need to end a string with null character? Answer is simple, so we could know that where string is ending.

```
while(*ps){
  ps++;
  i++;
} 
while(i>=0){
ps--;
*pre = *ps;
pre++;
--i;
}
*pre='\0';
```

Here in first while loop `*ps` and `i` will increment until `*ps!='\0'`. And in second while loop run until `i >= 0` is true. `*ps` decrement and assign `*ps` data to `*pre` so string can be reversed. And when second while loop ends `*pre='\0'` you are ending the reverse string with null character.

long story in short :)
when you enter string through `scanf("%s",s);` compiler will end add the null character at the end of string. But when you manipulate (reversing) the string you have to end reverse string with null character at the end. and that's what you have done by `*pre='\0';` this line.

To make more sense about it you should make basic string program and read about *string*.

Comment: I got another problem. *pre='\0' is ok but there was no adress in it. I'm used to *pre[number].
 
So, Is it right that *pre will point to the newest address? 
At first, *pre=string[0], after *pre=*pre+n (7 for example), *pre now points at   string[n+1] ( *pre=string[8] )?